# If $NP \neq coNP$ then $BPP \neq NP$

Tags: complexity-theory

I am new in complexity theory and I am trying as part of an assignment to prove or disprove this.

I am thinking this is a true statement but I am not sure how to prove or disprove it or what the implications of $NP \neq coNP$ are to randomized complexity classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28036/why-is-bpp-closed-under-complement) for an explanation on why $BPP=co-BPP$.

I'm sure you can solve from here :)

Comment: Im not sure how the fact that BPP = coBPP helps with proving or disproving the above statement.

Comment: @Gaussbaby Try a [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).